# Android and google maps api v2 manifest error

Tags: android, google-maps, android-manifest

I'm trying to run simple app with maps, here is my manifest.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.gpsWakeUpper"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.access_coarse_location"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.access_fine_location"/>
    <uses-feature
            android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
            android:required="true"/>
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <activity android:name="MyActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
            <meta-data
                    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                    android:value="xxx"/>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

and my main activity

```
package com.example.gpsWakeUpper;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    static final LatLng WROCLAW = new LatLng(51.06, 17.01);
    private GoogleMap map;

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        if(map!=null)
        {
            Marker wroclaw = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(WROCLAW).title("Wroclaw"));
            map.moveCamera((CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(WROCLAW, 15)));
        }
    }
}
```

For me it looks like everything is ok but i recive error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A required meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not exist.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

So i' wondering whats wrong with my androidmanifest file, any ideas or clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put both Maps related `<meta-data>` elements as direct "child"  of  `<application>` - you placed it as part of `<activity>` which is too deep and wrong. It should be like that:

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
    <meta-data
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
          android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
          android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
          android:value="xxx"/>

    <activity android:name="MyActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score -1):

**Add below lines in Manifest.xml**

```
<application 
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
<meta-data 
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
<meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
      android:value="AIzaSyBzJyhrJbxLDYoBVnWP8P2xrXXXXXXXXXX"/>
...........................
//your activities here
</application >
```